# get possible combination of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

100  ryan  music  2

200   kim   math  3

let say I have this dataframe

if I want to get a all combination of

```
[(100,200),(ryan,kim)...(2,3)] , 
[(100ryan,200kim),(100music,200math)......], 
[(100ryanmusic),(200kimmath).....]  
[(100ryanmusic2),(200kimmath3)]
```

if I want to get an all relation tuple what should I do?

Comment: Try use itertools

Comment: itertools.combinations

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

example:

```
import itertools

data = 'ABC'
for i in range(1, len(data) + 1):
    comb = itertools.combinations(data, i)
    print(list(comb))
```

output:

```
[('A',), ('B',), ('C',)]
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]
[('A', 'B', 'C')]
```